# Do Grails Domain Methods Create Mysql Triggers?

Tags: grails

I can't seem to find this information anywhere. If I add domain methods to a grails domain class, are they set up as mysql triggers or do they just run in the project? Especially "default" triggers that have overlap like beforeUpdate or beforeInsert. There's no documentation on exactly how these methods are being set up.

Comment: They can create basic indexes but not triggers. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they do not. GORM does not create any triggers.